# Batch file SQL CMD; How to handle timeouts?

Tags: batch-file, timeout, sqlcmd

I'm running a batch file that uses SQLCMD to run a query against a remote database and write the results to a CSV. Is there a way to return something if the script times out? I usually see "database took to long to respond and the batch file moves on to the next item on the list, omitting the timed-out imte.

Comment: Maybe show us your batch file...?

Answer (score 0):

`sqlcmd` sets errorlevel to 1 if it fails, so you could test that.
Either
`sqlcmd >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 echo failed`
or
`sqlcmd >nul 2>&1 || echo failed`
should work. Do your processing in place of simple echo in my example. I suppressed output from `sqlcmd` for readability, but of course you don't need to do that (so you could log the error message as well)